# Encrypt file and storing it on the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, amazon-s3

I don't want to have a readable endpoint like this .com///something.jpeg

so one thing I could do is use hash (I'm using bcrypt) to mask whatever needed to be mask, but my question is will it have performances issue doing encrypting on the server side as I did not save the encrypted string into my db.

**Here's how I will do it.**

**Saving** 
Bcrypt user_id, blog_post and filename and save my file into storage

**Retrieving** 
Get all the related identifier from the db, bcrypt them and use the value to go get the endpoint of the file.

Am I doing it right?

Comment: It sure will have impact on performance. Why not create a uuid for the combination and store a reference?

Comment: Why not try and see the benchmark yourself? I know in node u can see how long does it take it the terminal.